# Best way to create a queue for handling request to REST Api created via Django

Tags: python, django, api, asynchronous, geospatial

I have the following scenario:

- Back end  => a geospatial database and the Open Data Cube tool
- API => Users can define parameters (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) to make GET
  requests
- Process => On each requests analytics are calculated and satellite
  images pixels' values are given back to the user

My question is the following: As the process is quite heavy (it can reserve many GB of RAM) how it is possible to handle multiple requests at the same time? Is there any queue that I can save the requests and serve each one sequently?

Language/frameworks => Python 3.8 and Django

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Celery + Rabbitmq/Redis is probably what you need.
In this configuration, your heavy processes become "tasks". When called with `.delay()` they go in the queue and are not handle by your main process anymore.

You might want to check the tuto

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: Hello, this combination is the most popular as I have seen. It will be the first that I will try. Thx so much.

Answer (score 0):

There are many asynchronous message queueing technologies that allow you to do this, lots of which have Python APIs too.

You probably want to use request-response messaging, to correlate the requests you get with the replies you want to send.

A message queueing technology will allow you to take the requests, store them on a queue, and have your server handle them when it's ready. Storing requests on a queue means that they won't get lost. This also allows your application to scale - as more requests come in, they can be dealt with by multiple application instances and still return only one result!

The answer above recommends celery, which is a great choice for this kind of project. Depending on the requirements you have, you can also use pymqi: https://dsuch.github.io/pymqi/examples.html or ZeroMQ: (example here for using a request-response pattern) [ZeroMQ - Multiple Publishers and Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713711/zeromq-multiple-publishers-and-listener/14714792) if you need technologies that are more heavy-duty.

Comment: Great, I will try ZeroMQ, thanks!