# How to wait program until the function give return value?

Tags: python, zeromq

I have code like this :

```
zmq = Zmq_Connector_Mod.DWX_ZeroMQ_Connector()
zmq._GET_HIST_INDICATORS_(_symbol, 'C1')
sleep(random() * 5 )
c1_path = zmq._GET_DATA_()

zmq = Zmq_Connector_Mod.DWX_ZeroMQ_Connector()
zmq._GET_HIST_INDICATORS_(_symbol, 'BASELINE')
sleep(random() * 5 )
baseline_path = zmq._GET_DATA_()

zmq = Zmq_Connector_Mod.DWX_ZeroMQ_Connector()
zmq._GET_HIST_INDICATORS_(_symbol, 'C2')
sleep(random() * 5 )
c2_path = zmq._GET_DATA_()

zmq = Zmq_Connector_Mod.DWX_ZeroMQ_Connector()
zmq._GET_HIST_INDICATORS_(_symbol, 'EXIT')
sleep(random() * 5 )
exit_path = zmq._GET_DATA_()
```

I have a problem when `zmq._GET_DATA_()` is running, it doesn't have returned value, because `zmq._GET_HIST_INDICATORS_()` function needs a couple seconds to return the value. I already used `sleep()`, but it's not efficient because when I try to run this code in another device that slower than mine, it just not helping. How to wait program from execute the `zmq._GET_DATA_()` until `zmq._GET_HIST_INDICATORS_()` has returned the value without using `sleep()` that need time, meanwhile every device has different running time to execute the code ?

Comment: What does it return if it's not ready yet?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DWX_ZeroMQ_Connector' object has no attribute 'indi_data'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a message queue, so there must be a documented async way of doing this, but you may try something like the following:

```py
exit_path = None
while exit_path is None:
    try:
        exit_path = zmq._GET_DATA_()
    except AttributeError:
        exit_path = None
        sleep(1)
```

This should check once every second to see if the data is available.

Comment: D'oh, right, use the updated code...

Comment: It's work perfectly what i want, thankss!

Answer (score 1):

Higher-level overview here: typically in asynchronous message queueing, there are a few patterns you can use  so you don't have to poll over and over:

1. Publish-subscribe
2. Get with wait
3. Request-reply
4. Message listener

---

1. This is implementable in ZeroMQ, e.g. https://rillabs.org/posts/pub-sub-with-zeromq-in-python and this stackoverflow question discusses it in detail: [ZeroMQ - Multiple Publishers and Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713711/zeromq-multiple-publishers-and-listener/14714792)
2. Get with wait is a pattern where a timeout is set for a get operation, it won't return an error until the time expires. On a typical `zmq.recv()` call, you can specify the timeout.
3. Request-reply is typically implemented where the requestor specifies a reply queue and does a get with wait operation. Using this means you'll know which returned message corresponds to each message you sent. https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter3/#Recap-of-Request-Reply-Sockets
4. Message listeners set up responsive objects that respond to events and can be implemented in various ways. Various message queueing technologies have this built-in, couldn't find a good zmq example but it's definitely implementable!

---

Other queueing technologies have these patterns implemented more readily, e.g. ActiveMQ, IBM MQ, RabbitMQ if you wanted to explore.

Comment: Yes, I will change my pattern soon, Thanks for the information!

Comment: No problem! There are lots of great async use cases to explore.